# Spawning multiples actors in multiplayer unreal engine

Tags: c++, networking, unreal-engine4

Hello I'm currently having a hard time with a project I'm working on.

It is a video game made using unreal engine 4 and i have to implement the network part on the project. So first of all, we have multiples pawn possessed by players, every player is allowed to spawn blocks(can be different type of blocks). We are currently using a Grid (an actor) that stores all the blocks in the world. We are using a GridManager ( an UObject) to manage the grid.

The GridManager can create AActor : BuildingAction, PushAction, FallingAction,  and all others action that can be applied to any blocks in the grid. So i know that for spawning theses action and block i need to call RPCS from either the PlayerController or the pawn. The problem is that because the gridManager manages the grid and Spawn the actions on the world, the actions dont work on multiplayer. I guess spawning them in the player controller would work but it would need a function for every type of block and a function for every types of actions on the player controller, this would make no sense to store these functions on the player controller. If anyone could help me finding a good way to make this work on the network , it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's a very hard question to answer. My suggestion would be carefully go through some of the excellent tutorials and examples that the unreal team provide on networked game play.

Comment: I tried going through multiple tutorial but all the tutorials i see are about doing simple actions like open door, shooting bullets, simple stuff that are clearly done by the character. In my case it is more like a living grid that can spawn actors more like an AI, this makes me think i didnt check for AI network on unreal i'll take a look at it.

Comment: Also, you'll probably get better answers at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com or the unreal answer hub: https://answers.unrealengine.com/index.html